# KendoDatePicker Multiple Formats

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

How to accept multiple formats in KendoDatePicker?

For example, to declare multiple formats similar to this (if format were to accept an array).

```
this.$('#dtToDate').kendoDatePicker({
            value: new Date(),
            min: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
            max: new Date(2049, 11, 31),
            format: ["MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy"]
        });
```

In order to accept a date with format of 12-10-2013 or 12/10/2013.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is parseFormat. format only accepts 1 value.

parseFormat is an array that

> Specifies the formats, which are used to parse the value set with
>   value() method or by direct input. If not set the value of the
>   options.format and options.timeFormat will be used. Note that value of
>   the format option is always used

Reference
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker#configuration-parseFormats

and jsfiddle example

```
$("#sampleDate").kendoDatePicker({
    format: "MM-dd-yyyy",
    parseFormats: ["MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy"]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85DUe/

the example will accept values in both the MM-dd-yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy and convert them to what is specified in format which is MM-dd-yyyy